# Django - remove items from select while maintaining the original query

Tags: django

I'm wondering if Django has the functionality to remove particular items from a select once they've been added. For example, lets say I have a query that looks like:

```
FooBar.objects.annotate(
    field_1=field_1,
    field_2=field_1,
    field_3=field_1
).filter(
    some_filter_set
)

would produce SQL like so:

select field_1, field_2, field_3 from foo_bar where some_filter_set
```

After the initial query has been made, I'd like to keep this query, and create another copy that is the exact same but distilled down to just field_1 in the select. Does Django give the functionality to directly edit the select?

The reason for this is that I have a very large dynamically generated query that needs to be used in a subquery. I'd like to take the final version of the query, copy it, change the select, and use that as the subquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like?

```py
values_list = ['field1', 'field2', ...]

# add or remove fields from the list as necessary:
...

queryset = FooBar.objects.filter(some_filter_set).values(*values_list)
```

Or, if you want to stick with `annotate`, we are using python, so:

```py
annotation_dictionary = {
    "new_field_name_1" : "field_name_1",
    "new_field_name_2" : "field_name_2",
    ...
}

# add or remove entries from the dictionary as necessary:
...

FooBar.objects.annotate(
    **annotation_dictionary 
).filter(
    some_filter_set
)
```